# Datalist doesn't render in html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use a datalist inside a form_for like so:

```
<%= form_for(informe_r_hematico) do |f| %>
...
<%= f.text_field :code, list: "code", :style => "width: 50px" %>
    <datalist id="code">
        <option value="abc"></option>
        <option value="def"></option>
        <option value="ghi"></option>
    </datalist>

...
<% end %>
```

The problem is that when the page renders I just get a plain text_field and all the datalist lines appear "greyed-out" in the html code, what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add  to an option

```
<%= f.text_field :code, list: "listcode", :style => "width: 50px" %>
<datalist id="listcode">
    <option value="abc"></option>
    <option value="def"></option>
    <option value="ghi"></option>
</datalist>
```

#### second edit

as name "code" already used by text_field, try to change id and list name from code to other name for example listcode

Comment: I have added the closing tags and the problem persists, I will update the question

Comment: Edit, I thought the <datalist> element would be a mix between select and text_field, I now see that it only autocompletes and is not meant to act as a drop-down selector